# "Authorization" Header propagation with Hot Chocolate and nswag API Client not working

Tags: c#, authorization, hotchocolate, propagation

Very strange issue on a C# project with few important things.

- Hot Chocolate for GraphQL
- Header propagation for forwarding the HTTP Headers to API's
- nswag generated API Clients

I followed the whole tutorial here: https://craftbakery.dev/http-header-propagation-aspnet-core/

And doesnt matter that I do:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>(
    c =>
    {
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Omg", "what the ...");
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "english");
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Okay");
    });
```

The target method is like in the guide.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHeaderDictionary Get()
{
    // Return all headers API received.
    return Request.Headers;
}
```

But the real output then is on direct call:

```
{
"Omg": [
    "what the ..."
],
"Accept-Language": [
    "english"
],
"Authorization": [
    "Okay"
]
}
```

And when I try it via the sample project (which uses the nswag generated API Client).

```
{
"Omg": [
    "what the ..."
],
"Accept-Language": [
    "english"
]
}
```

I searched in the whole project for `Authorization` because I tought it could be removed somehow. But must be in that "in between layer".

Some ideas what the issue could be?